# Dúvida com geração de pdf e envio via mpdf

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida. Eu estou gerando um arquivo.pdf a partir da biblioteca mpdf.
Após gerar eu salvo no servidor.
Bom, eu gostaria de gerar o arquivo pdf e não salvar no servidor e sim, enviá-los para o e-mail do cliente. Até porque os dados necessários eu os salvo no banco de dados.
Peguei um exemplo na web, porém, não envia.

O código de envio.

```
<?php>

//recuperando os dados do cliente

$cliente = $_POST['cli_nome'];
$email_cli = $_POST['cli_email'];

$mpdf=new mPDF();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina);  <<<<

$content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');

$content = chunck_split(base64_encode($content));
$mailto = $email_cli;
$from_name = 'Comercial SC';
$from_mail = 'meuemail@gmail.com';
//$replyto = 'sender@domain.com';
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$subject = 'Seu Boleto';
$message = 'Olá '. $cliente . '! Obrigado pela preferência.';
$filename = $arquivo;

$header = "From: ".$from_name." <" .$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed: boundary=\"".$uid. "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid. "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .=  "--" .$uid. "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content. "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
$is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);

$mpdf->Output();
exit;

?>
```

Está dando um erro aqui nesta linha:

```
$content = chunck_split(base64_encode($content));
```

Inclusive, aqui eu crio o corpo do arquivo `.pdf`:

```
//Criando arquivo pdf...
include('pdf/mpdf.php');

$pagina = '  <<<<<
 <html> 
    (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GERAR PDF, ANEXAR E ENVIAR POR E-MAIL:**
//Criando arquivo pdf...
//Instanciando a classe...
    include('pdf/mpdf.php');

```
$pagina = '
 <html> 
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
  .cab_boleto {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   }
   table.bordasimples {border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   table.bordasimples tr td {border:1px solid #FF0000;
   }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  </head>
```

- BOLETO PARA PAGAMENTO - 
  
  
    
    CAIXA ECONÔMICA FEDERAL | 104-0
     RECIBO DO SACADO
  
  
    Local para depósito: Agências da Caixa Econômica e Lotéricas.
     Data do vencimento: '.$vencimento.'

Beneficiado: Shalom Criartes - MEI - CNPJ: XX.XXX.XXX/000X-XX

Ag./Op /Conta: 00XX-0XX-000XXXX-X

Endereço do beneficiado: Rua XXXX dos XXX, 000 - Bairro XXXXX XXX - Bhte - MG - Cep. XX.XXX-XXX
  
  
    Data do documento: '.$hoje.' 
    Número do doc:  '.$ndoc.' 
    Data do processamento: '.$hoje.' 
    Espécie de documento: >>>>>  R$  <<<<
    Valor do documento:     R$'.$tg.'

* * * SR. Caixa, não receber após o vencimento. * * *

* * * Depósito referente a pagto de pedido em loja virtual.    * * *

Depositante: '.$cliente.' 
  
  
    Endereço: '.$endereco.',' .$numero.' - '.$comple.' - '.$bairro.' - '.$cidade.' - '.$estado.' - Cep:'.$cep.'
  
  
     
    CPF.: '.$cpf.' 
    Pedido nº: '.$numped.' 
  
  
    Obs.: Gentileza, após realizar depósito, enviar print do recibo com nºpedido, data e horário para Whatsapp 9-xxxxxxxx

```
  </body>
</html>
';
```

$numped= "SC".$pedido;
$arquivo = $numped . ".pdf";
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina);
$mpdf->Output('pdf/tmp/' . $arquivo, 'F');

// I - Abre no navegador
// F - Salva o arquivo no servidor
// D - Salva o arquivo no computador do usuário

//Anexando o arquivo.pdf e enviando para o e-mail informado pelo cliente...

//recuperando os dados do cliente... 
$cliente = $_POST['cli_nome']; 
$email_cli = $_POST['cliemail'];

// Incluir a classe no teu ficheiro
require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

//require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
//require_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

//Instanciar a classe para envio de email
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet    = 'utf-8';                  // Define o charset da mensagem
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                     // Permitir autenticaÃ§Ã£o SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';       // Define o servidor SMTP
$mail->Username   = 'meuemail@gmail.com';   // SMTP conta de usuÃ¡rio
$mail->Password   = '*********';                  // SMTP conta senha
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                              // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                         // TCP port to connect to

```
// Realizando o envio do email
```

try {
    // Remetente
    $mail->AddReplyTo('meuemail@gmail.com', 'Meu Nome');
    $mail->SetFrom('meuemail@gmail.com', 'Meu Nome');

```
// DestinatÃ¡rio
$mail->AddAddress($email_cli, $cliente);

// Assunto
$mail->Subject = 'Boleto de Pagamento';

// Mensagem para clientes de email sem suporte a HTML
$mail->AltBody = 'Olá '.$cliente . " segue em anexo o boleto para o pagamento do seu pedido";

// Mensagem para clientes de email com suporte a HTML
$mail->MsgHTML('<p>Olá ' . $cliente . ' ! Obrigado pela preferência! <br> Segue em anexo o boleto para o pagamento.</p>');

// Adicionar anexo
$caminho = 'pdf/tmp/';
$ficheiro = $arquivo;

$mail->AddAttachment($caminho.$ficheiro);

// Enviar email
$mail->Send();

//echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("O boleto foi enviado para o e-mail informado!")</script>');
session_destroy();
exit ($refresh);
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
// Mensagens de erro do PHPMailer
echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
// Outras mensagens de erro
echo $e->getMessage();
```

}

?>

//Obs.: Peguei este código na web e adaptei o mesmo para o meu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

- Salvar no servidor em uma pasta temporária
- Enviar anexado por e-mail com seu serviço de e-mail próprio
- Por fim, apagar o arquivo da pasta temporária no servidor

Comment: Como normalmente é realizada esta operação?

Comment: Qual delas? Eu faço de forma parecida aqui num sistema, só que ao invés de enviar por e-mail, ao gerar o .pdf, eu permito download do arquivo e logo em seguida apago da pasta temporária.

Comment: Certo David, porém eu gostaria de gerar o arquivo pdf e logo enviar para o email do cliente. É possível, sem armazenar em pasta temporária? Mesmo se no caso eu abrir o arquivo no navegador do cliente?

Comment: Não sei te dizer.

Comment: Me tire uma dúvida: nesta linha   $content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S'); preciso entrar com o nome do arquivo pdf gerado dessa forma?  $content = $mpdf->Output('$arquivo'', 'S');

Comment: Não, deveria ser `$content = $mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'S'); ` condiserando que $arquivo é uma string, por exemplo, `'arquivo.pdf'`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78157/discussion-between-xavier-and-david-alves).

Comment: Onde posto uma solução encontrada como forma de colaboração no stackoverflow?

Comment: Poste como resposta da sua própria pergunta :)